# Как мне подключить PHP в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Не хочу морочиться с Visual Studio Code, а в нынешнем проекте нужно использовать php, поэтому и спрашиваю, как в Visual Studio 2019 подключить PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте расширение из Market Place

[PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.PHPToolsforVisualStudio2019)

Оно в состоянии preview
Но думаю оно вам поможет